# How did this webpage disable text selection?

Tags: html, textselection

Hi I found this webpage today: http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/hoaxes/sister.asp

I couldn't figure out how it disable text selection. It's neither the conventional CSS or javascript method. Do anyone know how it disable the text selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the Javascript source:

```
<!--
var omitformtags=["input", "textarea", "select"]
omitformtags=omitformtags.join("|")
function disableselect(e){
  if (omitformtags.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase())==-1)
    return false
}

function reEnable(){
  return true
}

if (typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined")
  document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
else{
  document.onmousedown=disableselect
  document.onmouseup=reEnable
}
-->
```

When the user attempts to start a selection, `onselectstart`, it simply returns false, which disables the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple Javascript method.

```
document.onselectstart = function() { return false; }
document.onmousedown = function() { return false; }
```